# How to assign $_GET variable without refreshing the webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a table on my website that is populated with values for each row, and here is a sample code:

```
//JAVASCRIPT
<tr onclick="window.history.replaceState(null, null, 'myPage.php?ID=2');">
```

The URL is changing, however it does not assign $_GET variable in PHP when using 'history.replaceState' function

Here is code to check whether ID has been assigned:

```
//PHP
if (isset($_GET["ID"])) {
    // do something
}
```

I can use different function which is

```
//JAVASCRIPT
<tr onclick="window.location.replace('myPage.php?ID=2');">
```

Here, the URL is changing and the variable is actually populated with 2, however the website is refreshing as well which is something I want to avoid.

I checked many articles online and apparently you can use AJAX, however I have no experience in AJAX, that's why I could use some help

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: _“however it does not assign $_GET variable in PHP when using 'history.replaceState' function”_ - of course it doesn’t, _because_ you are not making an actual request to the server, so PHP doesn’t become active again at all.

Comment: _“I checked many articles online and apparently you can use AJAX, however I have no experience in AJAX, that's why I could use some help”_ - help with what exactly? Yes, AJAX is a way to update a server-side value without loading a “new page”. But reading up on the basics of how to use it, and trying & testing stuff first, is still your job in this instance. You can come back and ask, if you have specific problems. But as of now, this is just too broad.

Comment: "I checked many articles online and apparently you can use AJAX, however I have no experience in AJAX, that's why I could use some help" — So go to Google and type "Ajax tutorial"

Answer (score -1):

You need to use ajax
try this

```
//html
<tr onclick="sendData('file.php','2');">


//PHP file.php
if (isset($_GET["ID"])) {
    // do something
}
return true;




      //JS
    function sendData( file, id){

window.histor`enter code here`y.replaceState(null, null, file+'?ID='+id);
        $.ajax({
        url: file,
        type:GET,
        data:{ID:id},
         success: function(result){
               console.log(result)
            }});

    }
```